# jquery datatable pegar valores de um input

Tags: jquery-datatables

Fala Pessoal!

Preciso da ajuda de vocês!
estou utilizando o plugin jquery datatable para gerar uma tabela paginada dinamicamente em um modal, até ai tudo certo, mas dentro desta tabela tenho um input que preciso pegar o valor digitado após o usuário confirmar em um botão no evento clique, ai esta o problema consegui pegar o valor com o seguinte código:

```
$('#TabelaPecas2 > tbody  > tr').find("input[id^='txtQuantidade']").each(function(){
if($(this).val() != "")
{
       alert($(this).val());
}
});
```

mas retorna somente os inputs da primeira pagina.
no código abaixo estou conseguindo pegar os dados de todas as paginas mas não estou conseguindo pegar o valor digitado pelo usuário.

```
var table = $('#TabelaPecas2').DataTable();
table.rows().every( function () {
    var data = table.row( this ).data();
    //pega valores input da terceira coluna
    console.log($(data[2]).val());
});
```

**UPDATE**

Pessoal, a quem interessar consegui fazer da seguinte forma:

```
            var table = $('#TabelaPecas2').DataTable();
            table.rows().every( function ( rowIdx, tableLoop, rowLoop ) { 
                var dados = table.row( this ).data();
                var cell = table.cell({ row: rowIdx, column: 2 }).node();
                if ($('input', cell).val() != ""){
                    var objPecas = new Peca(dados[0], dados[1], $('input', cell).val());
                    objServico.pecas.push(objPecas);
                }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chefe eu tenho algo parecido. No caso minha tabela contém quantidades e itens recebidos. 
No caso as Rows eu criei coloquei  e no laçõ eu pego td.quantity
E no input eu faço o mesmo e coloco no find td.classe input
Acho que seria isto que você precisa.

```
 $("#table").find('tbody tr').each(function () {
                var quantityCashier = $(this).find('td.quantity');
                var quantityInput = $(this).find('td.received input');

            });
```

Comment: Obrigado, pela resposta mas consegui fazer da seguinte forma:                     var table = $('#TabelaPecas2').DataTable();
                    table.rows().every( function ( rowIdx, tableLoop, rowLoop ) { 
                        var dados = table.row( this ).data();
                        var cell = table.cell({ row: rowIdx, column: 2 }).node();
                        if ($('input', cell).val() != ""){
                            var objPecas = new Peca(dados[0], dados[1], $('input', cell).val());
                         objServico.pecas.push(objPecas);
                        }

Comment: Também dá, só achei extenso e confuso inicialmente porque dá pra simplificar. Talvez na manutenção do código fique mais difícil para entender posteriormente.